# Instanciando un objeto en un Switch

Tags: java, switch

He creado un programa para un curso donde tengo que mostrar un menú, el cual hago con Switch, y en la primera opción tengo que crear un objeto Vehículo con varios parámetros que se piden por teclado.

Si no se crea primero el objeto en los demás menús se debe de mostrar un mensaje que ponga (por ejemplo): "Primero debe de crear un vehículo".

Para empezar no se como hacer eso. Ya que había pensado en crear el objeto en el case1 o al menos instanciarlo ahí.

Pero si lo creo o lo instancio en el case 1 no me compila, lanzando el siguiente error:

(Es muy largo, copiaré las primeras líneas que creo que son las importantes)

> Error: Unable to initialize main class PROG05_Ejerc1.Principal
> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
> Exception Details:
> Location:
> PROG05_Ejerc1/Principal.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @405: aload_3
> Reason:
> Type top (current frame, locals[3]) is not assignable to reference type
> Current Frame:
> bci: @405
> flags: { }
> locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;', integer, integer }
> stack: { }
> Bytecode:
> 0000000: 033c 033d 1207 b800 09b8 000f 3c1b aa00
> 0000010: 0000 025f 0000 0001 0000 000a 0000 0036
> 0000020: 0000 0187 0000 01a6 0000 01b6 0000 01e7

Sin embargo, si el objeto lo creo y lo instancio al comienzo del método main, el programa funciona perfectamente.

¿Sabéis por qué puede deberse eso?

¿Y cómo podría hacer para lanzar un aviso si se pulsa una opción del menú diferente a la 1 sin antes haber creado un vehículo con los datos pedidos?

Gracias. Un saludo.

------------- CÓDIGO DE LA CLASE PRINCIPAL ------------------

```
public class Principal {                                        // Clase donde se ejecutará el programa.

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {       // Método donde irá el código que el usuario final verá por pantalla.
    // TODO code application logic here
    
    int menu = 0;                                               // Variable donde se almacenará la elección que el usuario quiera del menú.
    int precioTemporal = 0;                                     // Variable para comprobar el precio introducido y avisar al usuario de que algo ha ido mal.
    
    //Vehiculo coche = new Vehiculo();
    Vehiculo coche;
    
    do {
     
        menu = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("----------------------------------------\n" + 
                "--  MENÚ  -      (Eliga una de las opciones          --\n" + "----------------------------------------\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  1  ----      Nuevo Vehículo                         ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  2  ----      Ver Matrícula                             ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  3  ----      Ver Número de Kilómetros         ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  4  ----      Actualizar Kilómetros                ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  5  ----      Ver Años de Antigüedad            ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  6  ----      Mostrar Propietario                    ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  7  ----      Mostrar Descripción                  ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  8  ----      Mostrar Precio                           ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  9  ----      Salir                                           ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------"));
        
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                
                coche = new Vehiculo();
                coche.setMarca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("VAMOS A CREAR UN NUEVO VEHÍCULO\n" + "\n" + "Introduce la marca del vehículo"));
                coche.setMatricula(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la matrícula del vehículo"));
                
            case 2:
                
                if (coche == null) {
                    System.out.println("Primero tienes que crear un nuevo Vehículo con la Opción 1.");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La matrícula del vehículo es: \n" + coche.getMatricula());
                }
                
                break;
                
    } while (menu != 9);
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Muchas gracias por utilizar nuestro Software.");
    System.out.println("Esperamos que vuelva pronto.");
    System.out.println("Pozo Software S.A");
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para saber si un objeto esta creado, tendrias que compararlo con null... con eso alcanza... el otro error, sin ver el codigo que lo genero es dificil... y no copies todo tu codigo, aprende a hacer un [mcve]... la mayor parte de tu codigo, es irrelevante a tu problema...

Comment: Creo que he recortado lo suficiente el código para simplificar la pregunta. Si lo comparo con null no hace nada y me muestra el else del condicional.

Comment: Además al crear el objeto vacío en el main antes del switch, me crea las variable int de kms a 0 y ya no es un objeto null, ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

según veo tu programa solo debe crear una instancia de la clase vehículo y mediante setters cambiar los datos a tu antojo,muy diferente seria que quisieras crear diferentes vehiculos y obtener sus datos de cada uno,para eso usarias un List o un Arraylist,al grano...el objeto clase deber ser inicializado pero no como null,por que no puedes usar setter con un objeto null,entonces lo inicializas como un new Vehiculo() y listo ya puedes hacer uso de ese objeto y cambiar los datos que quieras ojo solo de ese único objeto(coche) con respecto a las opciones donde te pide crear un vechiculo antes en vez de hacer una condicional en base a coche,hazlo mediante getter por ejemplo si quieres saber la marca sin nisiquiera haber creado un vehiculo,pones if(vehiculo.getMarca()==null)falta iniciar vechiculo y asi con el resto... espero haberte ayudado

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class Principa {       // Clase donde se ejecutará el programa

public static void main(String[] args) {       // Método donde irá el código que el usuario final verá por pantalla.
    // TODO code application logic here
    
    int menu = 0;                                               // Variable donde se almacenará la elección que el usuario quiera del menú.
    int precioTemporal = 0;                                     // Variable para comprobar el precio introducido y avisar al usuario de que algo ha ido mal.
    
    //Vehiculo coche = new Vehiculo();
    Vehiculo coche=new Vehiculo();
    
    do {
     
        menu = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("----------------------------------------\n" + 
                "--  MENÚ  -      (Eliga una de las opciones          --\n" + "----------------------------------------\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  1  ----      Nuevo Vehículo                         ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  2  ----      Ver Matrícula                             ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  3  ----      Ver Número de Kilómetros         ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  4  ----      Actualizar Kilómetros                ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  5  ----      Ver Años de Antigüedad            ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  6  ----      Mostrar Propietario                    ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  7  ----      Mostrar Descripción                  ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  8  ----      Mostrar Precio                           ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------\n" + "-  9  ----      Salir                                           ----\n" +
                "----------------------------------------"));
        
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
            
               coche.setMarca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("VAMOS A CREAR UN NUEVO VEHÍCULO\n" + "\n" + "Introduce la marca del vehículo"));
                coche.setMatricula(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la matrícula del vehículo"));
                
            case 2:
                
                if (coche.getMatricula() == null) {
                    System.out.println("Primero tienes que crear un nuevo Vehículo con la Opción 1.");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La matrícula del vehículo es: \n" + coche.getMatricula());
                }
                
                break;
                
    }} while (menu != 9);
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Muchas gracias por utilizar nuestro Software.");
    System.out.println("Esperamos que vuelva pronto.");
    System.out.println("Pozo Software S.A");
}

}
```

Comment: Entiendo a lo que te refieres. Pero el siguiente problema no se como resolverlo: Creo un coche vacío. Al instanciarlo, algunas variables se crean automáticamente, como por ejemplo el número de KMs. En las cadenas de texto puedo compararlas con null, pero con las variables numéricas no puedo y además no puedo compararlo a cero porque podría ser KMs 0.

Comment: podrias manejarlo como tipo String y cuando requieras usarlo para una suma resta o comparacion usas Integer.parseInt()

Comment: Eso he hecho al final. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: O podría usar `Integer` en vez de `int`. El valor por defecto de `int` (por ser un primitivo) es 0, el de `Integer` es `null` e `Integer` no es más que un wrapper de `int`, funcionan exactamente igual (de hecho puedes asignar un `Integer` a un `int`!)